# Creating class to work with Serial Port

Tags: c#, serial-port

**My Goal**: I have HASP with whom I need to communicate using Serial port.
The thing is many functions from different threads may want to communicate to this HASP - and I want some synchronization to occur.

**What I did**: I created wrapper class called `HASPClass`. Looks like this:

```
class HASPCLass
{
  SerialPort m_port;
  HASPClass(..)
  {
    //..  Init some other properties
    m_port.Open();
    //..
  }
  void CustomWriteToHASP()
  {
    //.. Do something
    m_port.Write(...);
  }
  void CustomReadHASP()
  {
    //.. Do something
    m_port.Read(...);
  }
  void Close () 
  {
   //Some code to close m_port
  };
}
```

Usage of this class would be:

Function1 from some thread:

```
HASPClass o = new HASPClass(..);
o.CustomWriteToHASP(..)
```

Function2 from other thread:

```
HASPClass o1 = new HASPClass(..);
o1.CustomReadHASP(..)
```

**Problem1**: Now if `o` didn't close the `m_port` - constructor of `o1` will throw since port is open.
I want to avoid this and make `o1` wait for `o` to finish job.

**What I thought**: Maybe I should make `m_port` static - and put static lock everywhere it is used in `HASPClass`, will it solve above problem? Also the constructor will be changed to only open static `m_port` *if it is closed*. Will this approach solve most of the problems I outlined before?

---

**Update**: My other problem is that different objects might specify different parameters (baud rate etc.) in constructor - so I encounter a problem :( since I have single static `m_port`. :(. What to do in such case?? (**I could relax this requirement and say all objects will put same parameters in constructor, but will it help?**)

Comment: Didn't you [ask this already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35086242/writing-class-which-encapsulates-serial-port-which-might-be-used-also-by-many-th)?

Comment: @MattBurland Nope removed that and this is more clarified

Comment: Use a singleton pattern. Don't create new `HASPClass` objects and instead have a `GetInstance` (or something similar) method that will return a static instance of `HASPClass` (or create it if it doesn't already exist).

Comment: @MattBurland I am somewhat new to .NET and not familiar with Singleton's - I would appreciate feedback on the approach I currently have. Also when did some research creating good singleton seems involved.

Comment: @MattBurland Or could you show some example?

Comment: Could you answer please, is it possible to perform 2 operations in parallel on the same port? The code will depend on this.

Comment: Or the logic you need is like as "open-dosomething-close" is a 'solid, interruptable' operation?

Comment: @MobileX I guess no. I am using blocking read and write and plan to put locks around read and writes. Read and writes are called on m_port.

Comment: @MattBurland Also I think singletons with parameters are troublesome? Like I said when initializing constructor should take parmeters like baud rate etc. Also what happens if method of singleton throws? How will serial port again be opened in another call?

Comment: @MobileX Yes that is possible that scenario

Answer (score 1):

A simple singleton pattern might look something like this:

```
class HASPClass
{
  private static HASPClass _instance;

  private HASPClass(..)
  {
    //..  Init some other properties

  }

  public static GetInstance(...)
  {
      // Note, if called with different parameters then this will be
      // quite a bit more complicated
      if (_instance == null) 
      { 
          _instance = new HASPClass(...)
      }
      return _instance;
  }
}
```

Now when you call it, you'd do something like:

```
HASPClass o = HASPClass.GetInstance(..);
o.CustomWriteToHASP(..)
```

But...since you are multithreading, this pattern won't be safe. You'll need to implement some locking around the critical `GetInstance` section to ensure that you don't create more than one object. So you could do something like:

```
  private static object lockObj = new object();
  public static GetInstance(...)
  {
      // Note, if called with different parameters then this will be
      // quite a bit more complicated
      if (_instance == null) 
      { 
          lock (lockObj)
          {
              if (_instance == null)
              {
                  _instance = new HASPClass(...)
              }
          }
      }
      return _instance;
  }
```

Better than manually locking would be to use [Lazy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx), but that might be complicated if you need to pass parameters. If (as I assume) those parameters are only ever passed once, you might want to have a separate initialization function that will store those parameters so you don't need to pass them when you get your instance.

If the parameters are the same every time, you could maybe try something like this:

```
class HASPClass
{
    private static ParameterObject _parameters;

    private static Lazy<HASPClass> _instance = new Lazy<HASPClass>(() => 
    {
        if (_parameters == null) 
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can get instance before initializing");
        }
        return new HASPClass(_parameters);
    });

    public static HASPClass Instance
    {
       get { return _instance.Value; }
    }

    private HASPClass(ParametersObject parameters)
    {
        // create and populate your object using values from parameters
    }

    public static void Initialize(ParameterObject parameters)
    {
        if (_parameters != null) 
        {
            // you might throw an exception here if this is not allowed
            // Or you might drop and recreate your object if it is allowed
        }
        _parameters = parameters;
    } 
}
```

You may or may not need to have locking around `Initialize`, but the idea would be that you'd probably call `Initialize` first from a parent thread so that it never needs to be called again from any other thread.

Comment: Thank you - I commented above and will comment here too: (1) Indeed I need to initialize this class with parameters like baud rate etc. (2) What happens if some method throws? Will the port be closed? Who will reopen the port? I would appreciate feedback from you I am also a bit beginner with .NET

Comment: @user200312: You can pass parameters to `GetInstance`, but if those parameters are likely to change, then you can't use the same object, (or at least, not the same underlying port). It's not clear if you expect those to change or not (i.e. thread 1 has a different baud rate than thread 2).

Comment: Thank you I will figure that out that is good question - for now let's assume they will all use same parameters - e.g. same baud rate etc.

Comment: But you've said that reads and writes are performed on the same opened port? Now you say that each "user" can open the port in different way?

Comment: Anyway you can store initialization parameters and check if they fit the newly provided. If the new ones are different - close and re-open.

Comment: @MobileX Users can't open port in different way - that is assumption now

Comment: @MattBurland Can you please also comment on my current approach in question? I think that will also work, if I need same parameters for all HASPClass objects? Because in constructor I will check if port is already inited - and if yes, don't change properties of m_port

Comment: Matt has provided a good solution. It's a bit common as we don't know all the details. But you can extend it in the way you need.

Comment: " if yes, don't change properties of m_port" - you need to make the m_port **static** in order to go this way. And don't forget to lock "everything" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class HASPCLass
{
  static SerialPort m_port;

  HASPClass(..)
  {
    lock(m_port)
    {
       if (!Initialized())
       {
         Initialize();
       }
    }
  }
  void Close () 
  {
    lock(m_port)
    {
       if (Initialized())
       {
         Uninitialize();
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: (1) This is continuation of my approach right? (2) I guess I do all parameter initialization in Initializa method? (3)This works only if users need my class using similar parameters right? e.g. same baud rate etc. ??

Comment: 1)Right. 2)You pass the parameters into HASPClass() constructor and than to the **private** Initialize method. 3)This works in any case, however once initialized the component will work with the baud specified. Until Close() method is called. After Close it can be initialized with another baud rate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more variant of the code for you. It should work in any case. It reopens the port in case of different baud rate requested.

```
class HASPCLass
{
  private static SerialPort m_port;
  private static bool m_initialized;
  private static int m_baudRate;

  public HASPClass(int baudRate)
  {
    lock(m_port)
    {
       if (!m_initialized)
       {
         Initialize(baudRate);
       }
    }
  }

  private Initialize()
  {
     m_port.open(baudRate);
     m_baudRate = baudRate;
     m_initialized = true;
  }

  private Uninitialize()
  {
     m_port.close();
     m_initialized = false;
  }

  private ReinitializeIfNeeded(int baudRate)
  {
     if (baudRate != m_baudRate)
     {
        Uninitialize();
        Initialize(baudRate);
     }
  }

  public void Read(int baudRate, out buff) 
  {
    lock(m_port)
    {
      ReinitializeIfNeeded(baudRate);
      m_port.Read(out buff);
    }
  }

  public void Write(int baudRate, in buff) 
  {
    lock(m_port)
    {
      ReinitializeIfNeeded(baudRate);
      m_port.Write(buff);
    }
  }

  public void Close() 
  {
    lock(m_port)
    {
       if (m_initialized)
       {
         Uninitialize();
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this variant cover both cases? If I need to reinitialize and without it? (I think it is better to lock onto something else than m_port - but that is different topic)

Comment: As you can see it does. You can use a separate object to lock on.